# MATLAB localmax() function returns indexes in 1D vector

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, vector

In order to calculate local maximums of 2D matrix Y, I use this

```
[~, indices]= localmax(Y);
```

But the `indices` is 1D. How to convert it back to 2D so to access its corresponding element in Y?

Comment: Actually you don't need to convert back to 2D. You can use `Y(indices)` (linear indexing) to access those elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation for `localmax`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/localmax.html#outputarg_indices):

> Linear indices of the nonzero values of `lmaxima`. Use `ind2sub` to
>   convert the linear indices to matrix row and column indices.

For example:

```
inputmatrix = ...
    [3     2     5     3
    4     6     3     2
    4     4     7     4
    4     6     2     2];


[~,indices] = localmax(inputmatrix,4,false);
[I, J] = ind2sub(size(indices), indices);
```

---

Edit: I should have clarified as well. As @LuisMendo mentions in the comments above, you can access the elements of `Y` directly with these [linear indices](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) by using `Y(indices)`.